# Ending sentence with a prepositional word (in / to / about etc.)

Tags: prepositions

Is the word "in" the following sentence - correct?

> How can I know what universities you recognize **in**?

For me, it seems a little weird to end a sentence with a prepositional word, like in this case.

Are there any rules about that issue? (I mean when it's OK to end with a prepositional word)

Comment: Have you done any [research on this](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=ending+a+sentence+with+a+preposition&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), before you asked here?

Comment: I don't think  your sentence means what you thinks it means. What are you *trying* to say?

Comment: J.R I don't have any direction to research this topic.  

Catija, I mean to ask a big organization in which universities they are recognize.

Comment: Can you give more context? Rephrasing the sentence doesn't help clarify it in this case. Are you trying to ascertain whether or not they recognize the degree you've earned from a particular university?

Comment: Yes Catija, exactly.

Comment: @Dory - Did you click on the link in my question to you? There's plenty of information there about ending a sentence with a prepositional word.

Comment: You're right, I didn't noticed the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that prepositions can go at the end of the sentence in English such as in "Where do you come FROM?" and there are rules about this which you can research, but from the exchange with Catija it seems that you want to ask "Which university degrees do you recognize?" or "Which university degrees are recognized by your organisation?" In general prepositions are required by specific verbs and "recognize" doesn't need one.